# Download file from WebBrowser Control via WebClient

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using webBrowser control to login and fetching download link from an anchor tag. The link contains a dynamically generated .csv file (even this file is not accessible without login).

My download code looks like

```
Dim rLink = curElement.GetAttribute("href").ToString()
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
myWebClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie)
myWebClient.DownloadFile(rLink, "report.csv")
```

Above code fires on DocumentCompleted event

Comment: What issues are you running into?, any exceptions? etc? as it stands now its rather hard to answer without taking a stab in the dark. try to make your issue as clear as you can, Since we can't read minds ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It takes a bit long and creates a blank file during the process then it automatically deletes it on process completion. No exception thrown. Please let me know if its not clear yet?

Comment: hhm, that is odd yeah, i never ran into this issue so can't say i know how to fix it, have you tried using `WebClient.DownloadDataAsync()` and getting the downloaded data in its `DownloadFileCompleted` event? (might not actually do mutch but it would give you more info on the process of the download and getting closer to finding a solution)

Comment: or `DownloadDataCompleted` i think it was (5 min edit time elapsed or i would have edited original comment)

Comment: yeah very odd. seems like server is not sending data. i think it requires some specified cookies or i should approach differently any suggestions?? WebClient.DownloadDataAsync() doesn't seem to be helpful as I can see the file is blank.

Comment: trying it some other way it got this exception "Too many automatic redirections were attempted."